# Redirect using window.location doesn't work

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

I searched for a related post, but all attempts have not worked.

My problem, is that I'm trying to do a simple redirect in Javascript, using path+querystring. My code is below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Page1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="pesq" onclick="Redirect();"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function Redirect()
        {
          window.location.href = 'http://localhost:61267/Page1.aspx?q=name';            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

window.location.href is always set like `'http://localhost:61267/Page1.aspx'`.

I have tried using window.location.search but still without success.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace `onclick="Redirect();"` with `onclick="Redirect()"`.

Comment: As you don't prevent the default behavior of the event I would guess (without being able to test right now) that the _redirect_ triggered by the `submit` action _overwrites_ the action of the script.

Comment: @theonlyguti, doesn't work.

Comment: I think t.niese is right; try `onclick="Redirect(); return false;"` to squash the default submit.

Comment: @t.niese works perfectly!

Comment: another option is: window.location.replace("http://localhost:61267/Page1.aspx?q=name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need a form and submit button for just doing redirects.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Page1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    <input type="button" value="pesq" onclick="Redirect();"/>
    </div>

        <script>
        function Redirect()
        {
          window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

also i noticed some encoding issues that i was able to resolve by adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use document.location instead.

```
      document.location = 'http://localhost:61267/Page1.aspx?q=name';
```

Comment: Like Riad, it doesn't work for me, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Problem code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<input type="submit" value="pesq" onclick="Redirect();"/>
</div>
</form>
```

HTML elements, specifically, forms, have default events that occur when user actions take place. In your context, the `submit` event is probably being invoked when you click on that `input` box. You need to prevent the default event from happening by either returning false from the event handler, or calling `preventDefault`

```
<form onsubmit="Redirect(); return false;" id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="pesq" onclick="Redirect(); return false;"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

P.S.

The `onsubmit` handler will allow yourself to press the enter key and still have the same effect as would have happened if you just clicked the `input` box.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do either of the following:

1) For server side asp code:

```
<asp:button text="Navigate" onclientclick="Redirect()" value="pesq" runat="server" />
```

[See MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

2) if client side code:

```
<input type="button" value="pesq" onclick="Redirect();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only changed the input type, and it worked perfectly! Thanks to t.niese.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Page1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="button" value="pesq" onclick="Redirect();return false;"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function Redirect()
        {
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost:61267/Page1.aspx?q=name';                        
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```